# ReentrantLock - lock.unlock() doesn't release lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to create an application with a single tasks producer (boss) and multiple tasks consumers (employees). The boss will add more tasks from time to time, and is up to the employees to clear the tasks queue. The problem is the following: Only one consumer is doing all of the work, and once it finishes, the others start to work.

I've try using a ReentrantLock, but it appears as nothing changed.

```
package threads;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Store {

    public static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger tasksList = new AtomicInteger(7);
        Runnable boss = () -> {
            System.out.println("Boss: Good morning.");
            List<Runnable> employeeList = generateEmployeesList(5, tasksList);
            for (Runnable employee : employeeList) {
                employee.run();         
            }
            while(tasksList.get() > 0) {

                try {
                    lock.lock();
                    System.out.println("Work more!");
                    tasksList.incrementAndGet();

                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Boss: Time to go home.");
        };

        System.out.println("= Starting =");
        boss.run();

    }

    public static List<Runnable> generateEmployeesList(int amountOfEmployees, AtomicInteger tasksList){
        List<Runnable> employeeList = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfEmployees; i++) {
            employeeList.add(createEmployee(i+1, tasksList));
        }
        return employeeList;
    }

    public static Runnable createEmployee(int employeeNumber, AtomicInteger tasksList) {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println("Thread #" + (employeeNumber) + " Started. Missing tasks: " + tasksList.get());
            while(tasksList.get() > 0) {

                try {
                    lock.lock();
                    System.out.println("Thread #" + (employeeNumber) + ". Task completed: " + tasksList.decrementAndGet() +" tasks left.");
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Thread #" + (employeeNumber) +": Finished.");
        };
    }

}
```

Results (wrong):

```
= Starting =
Boss: Good morning.
Thread #1 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #1. Task completed: 6 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 5 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 4 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 3 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 2 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 1 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 0 tasks left.
Thread #1: Finished.
Thread #2 Started. Missing tasks: 0
Thread #2: Finished.
Thread #3 Started. Missing tasks: 0
Thread #3: Finished.
Thread #4 Started. Missing tasks: 0
Thread #4: Finished.
Thread #5 Started. Missing tasks: 0
Thread #5: Finished.
Boss: Time to go home.
```

Expected results (random consumer decrements the tasks variable):

```
= Starting =
Boss: Good morning.
Thread #4 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #4. Task completed: 6 tasks left.
Thread #2 Started. Missing tasks: 6
Thread #2. Task completed: 5 tasks left.
Thread #4. Task completed: 4 tasks left.
Thread #1 Started. Missing tasks: 4
...
Thread #1: Finished.
Thread #2: Finished.
Thread #3: Finished.
...
Boss: Time to go home.
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong? What can I do to solve my problem?

I modified the app to use threads instead of Runnables. But, I'm still getting the same issue.

```
class Lock {
    private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static final ReentrantLock getLock() {
        return lock;
    }
}

public class Store {


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Boss b = new Boss(5, 7);
        b.start();
    }

    public static List<Thread> generateEmployeesList(int amountOfEmployees, AtomicInteger tasksList){
        List<Thread> employeeList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfEmployees; i++) {
            employeeList.add(employeeFactory(i+1, tasksList));
        }
        return employeeList;
    }


    public static Thread employeeFactory(int employeeNumber, AtomicInteger tasksList) {
        return new Employee(employeeNumber, tasksList);
    }


}

class Employee extends Thread {
    int number = 0;
    AtomicInteger tasksList;
    public Employee(int number, AtomicInteger tasksList) {
        this.number = number;
        this.tasksList = tasksList;
    }
    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Thread #" + number + " Started. Missing tasks: " + tasksList.get());
        while(tasksList.get() > 0) {

            try {
                Lock.getLock().lock();
                System.out.println("Thread #" + number + ". Task completed: " + tasksList.decrementAndGet() +" tasks left.");
            } finally {
                Lock.getLock().unlock();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Thread #" + number +": Finished.");
    }

}

class Boss extends Thread {
    int employees = 0;
    AtomicInteger tasks;

    public Boss(int employees, int numberOfTasks) {
        this.employees = employees;
        this.tasks = new AtomicInteger(numberOfTasks);
    }

    public void start() {
        List<Thread> employeeList = Store.generateEmployeesList(employees, tasks);
        System.out.println("Boss: Good Morning!");
        for (Thread employee : employeeList) {
            employee.start();
        }
        while(tasks.get() > 0 ) {
            Lock.getLock().lock();
            try {
            System.out.println("Keep working!");
            tasks.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                Lock.getLock().unlock();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Runnables are not threads. Your code is single-threaded.

Comment: @shmosel I edited the class, but I'm getting the same issue :(

Comment: Your code has a race condition. Two threads could both execute `wile(tasksList.get() > 0)` and get 1. Then they'll both eventually call `decrementAndGet`, making `tasksList` negative.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think that's the reason I use the lock in the first place ...

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl Right, but you're misusing the lock. Each thread makes an irrevocable decision to call `decrementAndGet` without holding the lock. So what does the lock protect? Answer: Nothing.

Comment: You're completely right. My mistake, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this code. You're misunderstanding how to use Runnables. The Runnable#run() method simply runs the code you create in the thread you're currently in. You have to create a separate thread to run them if you want some parallelism.

```
// Change this
employee.start();
// to this:
Thread t = new Thread(employee);
t.start();
```

Second, as a commenter mentioned you're not locking the access to the Atomic correctly. So, even though it's thread safe within single operations to itself it is not consistent across multiple invocations especially if your behavior depends on previous results, which you do. This is why if you made the single change above you'd see output something like below:

```
= Starting =
Boss: Good morning.
Work more!
Thread #2 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #1 Started. Missing tasks: 8
Thread #4 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #3 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #1. Task completed: 7 tasks left.
Thread #5 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #5. Task completed: 6 tasks left.
Thread #2. Task completed: 5 tasks left.
Thread #4. Task completed: 4 tasks left.
Thread #3. Task completed: 3 tasks left.
Thread #5. Task completed: 2 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 1 tasks left.
Thread #2. Task completed: 0 tasks left.
Thread #4. Task completed: -1 tasks left.
Thread #3. Task completed: -2 tasks left.
Boss: Time to go home.
Thread #5: Finished.
Thread #1: Finished.
Thread #4: Finished.
Thread #2: Finished.
Thread #3: Finished.
```

Between observing that there are tasks left

```
tasksList.get() > 0
```

and 'taking' one task

```
tasksList.incrementAndGet();
```

another thread may have taken a task. This is what you see with the negative counts. The operations must both exist in the loop or some other method of synchronization must be used like the built in Object sync methods:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Store {

    public static Object sync = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger tasksList = new AtomicInteger(7);
        Runnable boss = () -> {
            System.out.println("Boss: Good morning.");
            List<Runnable> employeeList = generateEmployeesList(5, tasksList);
            for (Runnable employee : employeeList) {
                Thread t = new Thread(employee);
                t.start();
            }

            synchronized (sync) {
                while(tasksList.get() > 0) {
                    try {                        
                        System.out.println("Work more!");
                        tasksList.incrementAndGet();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            sync.wait(1500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Boss: Time to go home.");
        };

        System.out.println("= Starting =");
        boss.run();

    }

    public static List<Runnable> generateEmployeesList(int amountOfEmployees, AtomicInteger tasksList){
        List<Runnable> employeeList = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfEmployees; i++) {
            employeeList.add(createEmployee(i+1, tasksList));
        }
        return employeeList;
    }

    public static Runnable createEmployee(int employeeNumber, AtomicInteger tasksList) {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println("Thread #" + (employeeNumber) + " Started. Missing tasks: " + tasksList.get());
            synchronized (sync) {
                while (tasksList.get() > 0) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Thread #" + (employeeNumber) + ". Task completed: "
                                + tasksList.decrementAndGet() + " tasks left.");
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            sync.wait(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thread #" + (employeeNumber) +": Finished.");
        };
    }
}
```

Yielding:

```
= Starting =
Boss: Good morning.
Thread #2 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #3 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Work more!
Thread #4 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #1 Started. Missing tasks: 7
Thread #3. Task completed: 7 tasks left.
Thread #5 Started. Missing tasks: 8
Thread #2. Task completed: 6 tasks left.
Thread #5. Task completed: 5 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 4 tasks left.
Thread #4. Task completed: 3 tasks left.
Thread #2. Task completed: 2 tasks left.
Thread #1. Task completed: 1 tasks left.
Thread #3. Task completed: 0 tasks left.
Thread #4: Finished.
Thread #5: Finished.
Boss: Time to go home.
Thread #3: Finished.
Thread #2: Finished.
Thread #1: Finished.
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it makes sense.